# How to dispatch a job before running queue:work command

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, laravel-8, laravel-queue

I want to make queue for email notifications and this notification is used for logging into website.

So at the notification file I implemented `ShouldQueue` and then I ran `php artisan queue:table` & `php artisan migrate` on terminal successfully.

After that I changed `QUEUE_CONNECTION` on `.env` to database and finally tried to run  `php artisan queue:table` after runing `php artisan serve` but it freezes at all:

[image: terminal capture]

I even ran `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan queue:work` again but still freezes!

**UPDATE:**

As `user1994` suggests, I have to dispatch a job before running this command, but I don't know how and where to dispatch it.

Here is my `LoginToWebsiteNotification` class:

```
class LoginToWebsiteNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('u Loggedin')
            ->view('emails.login-to-website');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

And this is how I called this notification from `LoginController`:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    $user->notify(new LoginToWebsiteNotification());
    return $this->loggendin($request , $user);
}
```

So would you please help me out with this, I would really appreciate that!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The terminal is not frozen, it's just waiting for jobs to come in, you can try calling any of your jobs and you'll see that they are saved in the table and when you launch that command it executes all those jobs

Comment: @Sergio I have added an Update about this, would you plz check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not frozen, its just waiting for a job. So firstly dispatch a job and then you will see it working :)

Have a look at this official documentation about [Laravel dispatch a job](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#dispatching-jobs)

Answer (score 0):

Like *user1994* & *Sergio* said, "it's just waiting for a job". After you run your `php artisan queue:work`, you can go ahead and login through your application so that the notification can be dispatched. You can see your job being triggered in the console then.

You could also manually trigger a dispatch through `php artisan tinker`, then run:

```
User::find(1)->notify(new App\Notifications\LoginToWebsiteNotification)
```

If you don't like to keep your console open and running, you could use `sync` driver for your queue in development.